# Eclipse cannot recognise return value of vector

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector

I have been getting C++ to work in Eclipse. My code has always compiled but Eclipse has always been confused. It first started out with not being able to recognise any headers (iostream, fstream, GL/glut.h) and I eventually found out to add all the library paths manually.

Now all the errors have gone except one type of error involving vectors. Here are some examples:

```
list[i]._v2
```

list is of type vector . Edge is a class which does have _v2. I can fix this error by casting the return from the vector:

```
((Edge)list[i])._v1
```

There are other examples and they are all to do with using values returned by vector access without some kind of explicit cast.

Here is the way I compile:

```
g++ -o <exec> <files.cc> -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

So why does eclipse not know where to find anything, and why does it recognise vectors now, but not their return type?

EDIT: It compiles fine outside of eclispe, and always has. It also compiles and runs in eclipse fine (I am using my own makefile), but eclipse shows the errors in the code, live.

Comment: Complaining about eclipse not working is a really bad excuse for not switching to a real c++ ide like QtCreator. Just my two cents.

Comment: "Eclipse cannot recognise return value of vector" - rather the compiler, right?

Comment: Have you tried compiling using `g++` outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I have updated the original post with answers: Compilation works fine but Eclipse displays errors when I am editing/viewing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting a new project I realised what I think my problem was: eclipse wasn't recognising my files as being in a source folder. I created a project and pretended it wasn't from source, allowing Eclipse create a Hello World file (and set up the includes). Then I put my files in the src/ folder and everything works now.